# Why does my code say I have 4 arguments when I have 3?

Tags: tkinter

I have been editing a pong game by trying to add a score counter that bounces around a screen and bumps into the ball and paddle in order to make it more interesting. Whenever I run the program, for `if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:` it keeps telling me “list index out of range”. I have tried removing the Text class, but it returns a new error,” __ init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given” I can see that I only have three arguments in my init function. Does anyone know why these errors keeps popping up?

Hopefully this code will output the words Score: 0 bouncing around the screen.

```
score = int(0)
print ('Score: ' + str(score))
class Text:
  def __init__(self, canvas, color):
    global score
    self.canvas = canvas
    self.id = canvas.create_text(10, 20, text="Score: " + str(score), fill=color, font=("Arial", 15))
    self.canvas.move(self, 245, 100)
    starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
    random.shuffle(starts)
    self.x = starts[0]
    self.y = -3
    self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
    self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

  def draw(self):
    self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
    pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
    if pos[1] <= 0:
      self.y = 1
    if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
      self.hit_bottom = True
    if pos[0] <= 0:
      self.x = 3
    if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
      self.x = -3

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

text = Text(canvas, 'black')

while 1:
  if 1 > 0:
    text.draw()
  tk.update_idletasks()
  tk.update()
  time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Links to code on other sites is discouraged. Those errors all mean very specific things.  Search for those error messages and you'll likely find many similar questions.

Comment: You need to save the item ID of the canvas text item created inside `Text` class to `self.id` like that in the `Ball` and `Paddle` classes.  Note that it is not recommended to post code in link.  Also `Text` class will override the `Text` widget in `tkinter` module, that is why it is not recommended to use wildcard import.

Comment: `canvas.coords(self.id)` for a text item will return only one (x, y). Use `canvas.bbox(self.id)` instead.